# Return user to where they came from

Tags: ruby

Is there a way you can return a user to where they came from without having to go deep into else if statements?

Such as, say they came from here:

```
def start
  puts "Some code press 'E' to go to examples"
  input = gets.chomp
  if input =~ /e/i
    examples
  else
    start
  end
end
```

And they went to examples:

```
def examples
  puts "Examples of code to return to where you came from type 'return'"
  input = gets.chomp
  if input == 'return'
    #<= (return them to where they came from)
```

I know that in order to do this you call the method which would be `start` but I want them to return to where they came from no matter where they come from, be it `start, lesson_1, lesson_2, lesson_3` etc. Without having to make a ridiculous amount of if elsif else statements. Is there a way to do this without going super deep into if else statements?

Meaning;

```
if input == "y"
  start
  if input == "r"
    return 
    if input == "w"
      wait
    else
      return
    end
  else
    start
  end
else
   return
end
```

Comment: Just return from `examples` and control will come back to the caller, which is `start` method (in this case)

Comment: I'd have to go deep into else if statements to do it that way, that's what I'm trying to avoid..

Comment: what do you mean, "deep into `else/if` statements"? Post some of that so that we know what you are talking about.

Comment: Edited what I meant into it. I'm trying to avoid that, because I will have more then one place the users will be coming from.

Comment: You can use a case statement

Comment: And what I meant is to insert this line into your `examples` method: `return if input == 'return'`. This would return control into the calling method and it'll pick up where it was interrupted (that is, next line after invocation of `examples`). But this is transferring of "execution point". Whereas you seem to be asking about how to fix your interactive menu navigation. Looking at your code, this alone won't fix your navigation. As far as I see it, you need an input-handling loop instead of what you're doing there (grapping input and branching on it all over the place).

Comment: Awh okay, I'll look into it, thank you.

Comment: You need an event loop and case statements. You might also look into the PTY and expect modules, or https://github.com/avdi/greenletters to handle your keyboard interaction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sort of thing you're describing is solved by a [finite state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine).

Rather than having a big, complicated if/elsif block, you define states of your program and what states they can move into.  You can draw this out like a flowchart.

- Start the program -> `start`
- `start` -> `wait` or `start`
- `wait` -> `quit` or `start`
- `quit` -> Exit the program

The FSM can be done as a class, each state is a method. The methods only need to know about their next steps.

Here's [an article about state machines in Ruby](http://www.sitepoint.com/state-machines-in-ruby/) and [list of Ruby state machine libraries](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/state_machines.html).

Comment: For a FSM is there a gem I have to download to use?

Comment: @ekultek I've added some links to the answer.